# C++: Finding the highest value of a class within a linked list

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I'm working on an assignment that involves creating a linked list of applicants (stored as a class), each having a value for ID, grade, years, and a numerical value (score). I need to write a function that searches this list for the applicant with the highest score and returns it. I was able to locate the highest score, but I would only return that value, and not the entire class of that specific applicant. After changing my code, I now get outputs for each of the 4 values (ID, grade, years, and score) but they all show 0, which is the initialized value. Here is all the relevant code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "applicant.cpp"

using namespace std;

struct Linkapp
{
  Applicant person;
  Linkapp   *next;
};

class Linkthem
{
  protected:
    Linkapp *start;
  public:
    Linkthem(void);
    void link(Applicant);
    void printthem(void);
    Applicant returnbest(void);
};

Applicant best;

Linkthem::Linkthem()
{
  start = NULL;
};

void
Linkthem::link(Applicant one)
{
  Linkapp *p;
  p = new Linkapp;
  p->person = one;
  p->next = start;
  start = p;
}

Applicant Linkthem::returnbest (void)
{
    Linkapp *travel;
    travel = start;

    best = travel->person;

    while (travel != NULL)
    {
        if (travel->person.return_value() > best.return_value())
            best = travel->person;
        travel = travel->next;
    }

    return best;
}

int
main()
{
  ifstream infile;
  Applicant fellow;
  Linkthem mylist;
  int id, yrs;
  char knowledge;

  cout.setf(ios::fixed);
  cout.precision(2);

  infile.open("applicnt.dat");

  while ( !infile.eof() )
  {
    infile >> id >> knowledge >> yrs;
    fellow.store_id(id);
    fellow.store_skill(knowledge);
    fellow.store_years(yrs);
    mylist.link(fellow);
  }

  mylist.printthem();

  cout << best.return_id() << ' ' << best.return_skill() << ' ';
  cout << best.return_years() << ' ' << best.return_value() << endl;

  fellow = mylist.returnbest();

  return 0;
}
```

And from the "applicant.cpp"

```
class Applicant
{
  protected:
    int   id;
    char  skill;
    int   years;
    float value;
    void  calc_value(void);    // <--- NOT for general use, called by return_value
  public:
    Applicant(void);
    void  store_id(int);
    void  store_skill(char);
    void  store_years(int);
    int   return_id(void);
    char  return_skill(void);
    int   return_years(void);
    float return_value(void);
};
```

The problem definitely lies within my returnbest function, I'm just not sure where.

Comment: look at the order of calls - think about when the global variable `best` is updated and when you actually use it..

Comment: Any reason for not using ::std::list<Applicant>?

Comment: @Aconcagua: Probably because this is homework *"I'm working on an assignment"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you seem to have to write your own list, some hints:

Linkapp appears to be an internal detail of your class Linkthem, so no bad idea to make it a private inner class.

returnbest (and probably printthem, if I may assume analogous implementation) will fail with segmentation fault, if your list is empty. You need to check, if start is null first:

```cpp
if(start)
{
    // rest of your code
}
else
{
    // return some appropriate default
    // throw exception
    // or whatever else seems appropriate to you
}
```

You have quite uncommon names for your getters/setters. There are two main variants for naming:

```cpp
int getId(); // or get_id(), but cammel casing is more common these days
void setId(int id);
// vs
int id();
void id(int id);
```

There is no need for `Applicant best` to be a global variable. Rather place it within the functions as local variables.

Now your actual problem:
Keep a close look on your main function - where do you call returnbest first? *After* you wrote out the values of best. This means that you never assigned any other value to best than the default. You have to place `fellow = mylist.returnbest();` *before* the lines where you output best. But then use `fellow` for output instead of best, and you are free to make `best` a local variable within returnbest function...

Comment: Thank you so much for this response. It definitely helped out the most.

Answer (score 2):

Just used [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) and `std::list` (which is doubly linked) or `std::forward_list` (which is singly linked), but I would probably default to `std::vector` instead:

```
std::max_element(begin(list), end(list), [](Applicant const& a, Applicant const& b) {
    return (a.return_value() < b.return_value());
});
```

If the comparison function is intended for the entire `Applicant` class, it might make sense to define an `operator<` for said class.

Comment: While I agree with you, as this is homework, I am guessing he won't be allowed to hand in code that uses the standard library. I know I wasn't.

Comment: Yeah, as graham said, since this is for homework I cannot use the standard library. Thanks for the feedback though!

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist.printthem();

cout << best.return_id() << ' ' << best.return_skill() << ' ';
cout << best.return_years() << ' ' << best.return_value() << endl;

fellow = mylist.returnbest();
```

I don't know what you do in the `printthem()` member function, as you did not provide implementation of this function, but I assume you don't set variable `best`.So, you are printing an unset variable, which likely is initialized to zero.

What you want to do is more likely:

```
mylist.printthem();

best = mylist.returnbest();

cout << best.return_id() << ' ' << best.return_skill() << ' ';
cout << best.return_years() << ' ' << best.return_value() << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That was what the problem was.